# Правильная постановка запятой в СПП: "то(,) что" или ", то что"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, местоимения

1. Мне пора понять то, что экзамен требует серьёзной подготовки.
   или
2. Мне пора понять, то что экзамен требует серьёзной подготовки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В СПП с придаточным изъяснительным указательное местоимение желательно не употреблять, такие конструкции разговорные, на экзамене являются грамматической ошибкой. Должно быть:

*Мне пора понять, что экзамен требует серьёзной подготовки.*

"То" играло бы конструктивную роль в СПП с придаточным местоимённо-определительным, тогда  указательное местоимение легко заменялось бы на  определительное "всё":

*Мы обратились к тому, кто нам помог*.

В Вашем варианте запятая после ТО, указательное местоимение остаётся в главном предложении: пора понять (что?) то.